# ionic calling a service

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I defined a service in IONIC like this (file reddit.service.ts):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RedditService{
http:any;
baseUrl: String;

counstructor(http:Http){
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/r';
}

getPosts(category, limit){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/'+category+'/top.json?limit='+limit).map(res => res.json());
}
```

}

I am calling this service like this (file reddits.ts):

```
  getPosts(category, limit){
this.redditService.getPosts(category, limit).subscribe(response => {console.log(response);
});
```

The error Message I am getting is:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at RedditService.getPosts (reddit.service.ts:16)
```

Why I am getting this error? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
counstructor(http:Http)
```

should be:

```
constructor(http:Http)
```

and usually we just inject providers into constructor like...

```
@Injectable()
export class RedditService{
  baseUrl: String;

  constructor(private http:Http){
    this.baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/r';
  }    
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As the `HttpModule` used to be included in the `IonicModule` before, it no longer is, and therefore the `HttpModule` needs to be imported in the `NgModule` and set in the `imports` array.

Comment: You have *Eagle eyes* +1

Comment: @PankajParkar Haha, thanks. I'd rather say that sometimes I'm less blind that other times. So I guess I got lucky :D

Comment: many thanks! :)
However, now I get other error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!". Do you know what that could be?

Comment: @Adam Did you change the injection of the http? If so, did you remove `http:any` and `this.http = http;` and do you inject the constructor using `private http: Http`? You seem to have http imported, so problem is not there. Also I assume you have HttpModule imported? Just check the injection of http first and we'll see if it does not work then :)

Comment: @AJT_82: thanks for the quick reply :) I am actually trying to learn IONIC by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilM8YorL_jI&t=1611s I have come to somewhere around min 30. In the tutorial the guy is able to call the reddit service without declaring http as private and without importing HttpModule. Don't know why it is not working on my machine...

Comment: I have never used Ionic but I recently learned, that earlier the httpModule was part if IonicModule, but not anymore, so you actually need to import the HttpModule as well to your ngModule now. So add that to your imports array in your ngModule...`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: @Adam Please note that this plunker is a RC7 version of Ionic, so here it would actually work without having to import the http-module, BUT you are probably using newer than RC7, so therefore you need to import the HttpModule. So your setup should look something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gb1dooyOPq2UavB8PHlb?p=preview

Comment: @PankajParkar So it seems, +1 for that ;)

Comment: you guys are the best, especially you @AJT_82!
Many thanks once again - I added the import to my app.module.ts file and HttpModule to imports in the @NgModule. After that, it worked! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have `http` service haven't injected properly inside Service constructor. Also make sure you have imported `Http` & `Injectable` injector correctly.

```
@Injectable()
export class RedditService {
   //make sure you have below dependency inject with private access specifier.
   //since we mentioned it private, http will be available in component context 
   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   getPosts(category, limit){
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/'+category+'/top.json?limit='+limit).map(res => res.json());
   }
}
```

Additionally please add `HttpModule` in `imports` of your `AppModule` to make `http` API working.

Comment: I have updated my question above with the complete RedditService script. Can you review it please?